# Tracking PDFs through Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm hosting a website through Github and I have pdf files hosted on it. The pdf file is accessed by directly using the URL and not by pressing a link. So, the only way to access the PDF is by typing `http://website.com/resume.pdf`.

I was wondering if its possible to use google analytics to see who visits the specific PDF file, and how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics is usually implemented via clientsite (javascript) tracking code. Since you cannot embed that into a pdf document you cannot use it to track direct downloads.

What you can do (presumably, I'm not familiar with how Github hosting works) is to set up a "proxy" page that records the hit and then redirects the user to the download. You would redirect all requests to PDF files to this proxy page (via htaccess or similar) so your existing urls remain valid. Then you can track the hit (either via JS or serverside with the measurement protocol) and fetch the document based on the original request url.